# Google play warning - Webview is vulnerable to cross app scripting

Tags: android, webview

Maybe there are many developers who got this kind of message. i didnt find anywhere how to do, what to do in this case. i read this [Google play warning - Webview](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53095398/google-play-warning-your-app-contains-a-cross-app-scripting-vulnerability), but didnt get it. in `gradle` file `minSdkVersion 15 
targetSdkVersion 26`

i just can put codes from app. what row should i delete or what should i add?

**Manifest**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.com.com"
    android:installLocation="auto">

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity" 
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
      </application>
```

**MainActivity**

```
    private void initWebView() {
    webView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {
        @Override
        public void onPageStarted(WebView view, String url, Bitmap favicon) {
            super.onPageStarted(view, url, favicon);
            progressBar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            current_page_url = url;
            invalidateOptionsMenu();
        }

        @Override
        public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {
            super.onPageFinished(view, url);
            progressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            invalidateOptionsMenu();
        }

        @Override
        public void onReceivedError(WebView view, WebResourceRequest request, WebResourceError error) {
            super.onReceivedError(view, request, error);
            progressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            invalidateOptionsMenu();
        }
    });

    webView.setBackgroundColor(getSelectedItem());
    WebSettings webSettings = webView.getSettings();
    webSettings.setLayoutAlgorithm(WebSettings.LayoutAlgorithm.NARROW_COLUMNS);
    webView.getSettings().setBuiltInZoomControls(true);
    webView.getSettings().setSupportZoom(true);
    webView.getSettings().setDisplayZoomControls(false);
    webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    webView.setWebChromeClient(new WebChromeClient());

}
```

Comment: Did you resolve? How?

Comment: Just add `webView.getSettings().setAllowFileAccess(false);`

Comment: Make `setJavaScriptEnabled` to `false`. This is mentioned in the docs as : *Ensure that parameters to evaluateJavascript are always trusted. Calling evaluateJavascript using unsanitized input from untrusted Intents lets attackers execute harmful scripts in the affected WebView.*