# Android app rejected due Cross App Scripting Vulnerability

Tags: android, google-play, android-webview, crlf-vulnerability

My app is rejected from play store saying that webview vulnerability (Cross App Scripting Vulnerability).

After doing some R&D, I have added "android:exported=false" to the activites where I am using webview.

But again I received the same from playstore as App rejected due to Cross App Scripting Vulnerability.

Can anyone please suggest me what we need to do to overcome this issue and need to deploy to play store.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Google Play warning: Your app contains a Cross-App Scripting Vulnerability](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53095398/google-play-warning-your-app-contains-a-cross-app-scripting-vulnerability)

Comment: also check this out: https://support.google.com/faqs/answer/9084685?hl=en-GB

Comment: Thanks for the reply @umair. Will add meta data and will see any luck goes with.